# how to route custome url in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller

I have return my Controller with attribute routing like below.

```
    [Route("{CourseName}/{CourseCode}")]
    public ActionResult getAllProductList(string CourseName,string CourseCode)
    {
        ViewBag.CourseName = CourseName;
        ViewBag.CourseCode = CourseCode;

        return View("CoursePage");
    }
```

it works fine. but if there is any ajax method calls (for ex. ../controllername/methodname) from JS then its hitting my above controller/Action instead of "methodname" . Please suggest.

My RouteConfig Code:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CoursePage",
            url: "{CourseName}/{CourseCode}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Course", action = "getAllProductList" },
            constraints: new { CourseName = "\\d +", CourseCode = "\\d +" }
        );
```

Comment: what  url is the ajax method trying to access ?

Comment: url will be part of same domain. like "www.aaa.com/Products/getListProduct"